# How to update a BigDecimal attribute in Rails model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, bigdecimal

I have the following model JobRequest::Receipt.

The :amount attribute is a bigdecimal as you can see.

```
# Table name: job_request_line_headers
#
#  id                     :integer          not null, primary key
#  type                   :string(255)
#  job_request_id         :integer
#  merchant_company_id    :integer
#  merchant_id            :integer
#  default_setting        :boolean          default(FALSE)
#  payment_amount         :decimal(12, 4)
#  payment_state          :integer          default(0)
#  payment_at             :datetime
#  deleted_at             :datetime
#  published_at           :datetime
#  delivered_at           :datetime
#  created_at             :datetime
#  updated_at             :datetime
#  related_line_header_id :integer
#  amount                 :decimal(12, 4)
```

This is what the object looks like

```
> JobRequest::Receipt id: 24, type: "JobRequest::Receipt",
> job_request_id: 19, merchant_company_id: nil, merchant_id: nil,
> default_setting: false, payment_amount: nil, payment_state: 1,
> payment_at: nil, deleted_at: nil, published_at: nil, delivered_at:
> nil, created_at: "2016-03-07 06:58:49", updated_at: "2016-03-07
> 06:58:49", related_line_header_id: nil, amount:
> #<BigDecimal:7ffe424c7d48,'0.0',9(18)
```

If I try to update the amount attribute in any of the ways below it'll commit the SQL but it'll not update the value

pry(main)> JobRequest::Receipt.last.update_attribute(:amount, 22.3)

pry(main)> JobRequest::Receipt.last.update_attribute(:amount, BigDecimal.new(22.3, 5)

amount = BigDecimal.new(22.3, 5)

pry(main)> JobRequest::Receipt.last.update_attribute(:amount, amount)

any of those will return amount set to zero.

```
> [86] pry(main)> JobRequest::Receipt.last.amount   
JobRequest::Receipt
> Load (1.7ms)  SELECT  "job_request_line_headers".* FROM
> "job_request_line_headers"  WHERE
> "job_request_line_headers"."deleted_at" IS NULL AND
> "job_request_line_headers"."type" IN ('JobRequest::Receipt') AND
> "job_request_line_headers"."default_setting" = 'f'  ORDER BY
> "job_request_line_headers"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
> => #<BigDecimal:7ffe3be9bc40,'0.0',9(18)>
```

Any clues what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I just did it on a Bigdecimal field the following way on `herouku run rails console´:

```
$ i = Item.find(47)
$ i.selling_price = 25.00
$ i.save!
$ i.selling_price
```

`OUTPUT: BigDecimal:7f3cdfe1d598,'0.25E2',9(18)`